# How to upload documents to AWS S3 in this format domain_name/my_bucket_name/my_folder_name

Tags: angular, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload documents to AWS S3 directly by using angular.

I have followed this [tutorial](http://javasampleapproach.com/aws/angular-4-amazon-s3-example-how-to-upload-file-to-s3-bucket)

However I need to upload document to `https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket_name/my_file_name` and not `https://my_bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/my_file_name`

How can I achieve that. 
this is my method to upload.

```
uploadfile(file) {

    const bucket = new S3(
      {
        accessKeyId: 'my-ACCESS-KEY-ID',
        secretAccessKey: 'my-SECRET-ACCESS-KEY',
        region: 'my_region'
      }
    );

    const params = {
      Bucket: 'my_bucket_name',
      Key: this.FOLDER + file.name,
      Body: file
    };

    bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('There was an error uploading your file: ', err);
        return false;
      }

      console.log('Successfully uploaded file.', data);
      return true;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you upload your files to Amazon S3 is independent from the way you can access them later.

So, feel free to use your current method to upload if it works for you. You will need to supply the name of the **bucket** and the **key**, which is the filename including the full path (eg `my-folder/my-file`).

Once the file is in S3, you can access is via both methods:

- `https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_bucket_name/my_file_name`
- `https://my_bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/my_file_name`

You can also turn on [Static Website Hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/static-website-hosting.html), which has a different format to access the objects.

By the way, if you just want to get your files into S3 (and don't want to do it as part of an application), you can simply use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/). It has simple commands and runs on Windows, Mac and Linux.